# How can i Prevent the default "New Tag Scanned" pop-up using the 'nfc_manager' Plugin in Flutter on Android Devices?

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I am having a problem with reading NFC chips on Android phones. The problem is that when I scan one in my Flutter app, it opens a new window and it says "New Tag Scanned".

This is annoying because it leaves the app and I have to go back to it. I have tried searching for it but every if any solutions are for the "nfc_in_flutter" plugin, but I am using the "nfc_manager" one. I can't use "nfc_in_flutter" because it is outdated and incompatible with Dart 3.

Here are some sources I found:
https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter/issues/50

[nfc_in_flutter: How to prevent "New Tag Scanned" in android version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536809/nfc-in-flutter-how-to-prevent-new-tag-scanned-in-android-version)

[When app receives NFC data it opens "New Tag collected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849901/when-app-receives-nfc-data-it-opens-new-tag-collected?rq=4) // Best I found, but still doesn't work

Does anyone know how I can keep this window from opening?

Comment: What is the contents of the Tag? I would use the App NXP Taginfo https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/nfc-taginfo-app/ to do a full scan of the Tag and then use the save function to get a text file who's contents can be added to the question. The reason is that nfc_in_flutter has limited functionality and "Currently only NDEF formatted tags are supported." and there are lots of other Tag contents that are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently worked with the same package of Flutter NFC Manager and had the same problem:

Android system's NFC handler is interfering and opening the new window on tag scans, rather than the Flutter app handling it directly.

From what I've seen, basically, you need to have the correct flutter code to listen for the NFC tag, otherwise, the Android one will intercept the tag.

So, in your `initState` if you *don't* call:

```dart
NfcManager.instance.startSession(
  onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
    // Do something with an NfcTag instance.
  },
);
```

It will open the Android one since there's no code for handling the card.

So, the solution that I have is to `always listen` for an NFC tag, with:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  NfcManager.instance.startSession(
    onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      // Even if you're not doing anything here, it will still prevent the Android NFC handler from triggering.
    },
  );
}
```

whether I need to read the card or not. And since we're using the flutter nfc manager, it will override the Android manager.

Also, don't forget to dispose:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was same proble but after input below source code to *Flutterproject/android/app/src/main/kotlin/package_name/MainActivity*  . it worked for me(I have used [nfc_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager) package),after put below source to Mainactivity,open terminal -> **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get** and then try to run project.it worked for me .in my result it is not show "Scanned new tag" dialog

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val intent = Intent(context, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE )
    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context)?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null ,null )
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context)?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that too.